# calendar format using ajax

Tags: asp.net

When I am using ajax calendar it is a taking date in the format 07-17-2010 but I want the format as 07/17/2010. This means instead of - (hyphen) I want /(slash). Can we change this? If yes then how can we do this? Please help me.

my code is

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtstart" runat="server" Width="200px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"
        runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icon_cal.png" />
<asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtstart"
        Format="mm-dd-yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the format supposed to be:-

> MM-dd-yyyy

notice the uppercase MM, see this [post from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) to get a list of valid format strings

**Edit** The question has changed since I gave my initial answer. Can the format now be

> MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking it was a format like this but [apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(VS.71).aspx) not..

Maybe transform the value into a string and use [string.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)..